# How to deallocate the linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, free

This is my code.

```
struct node_struct {
    char *data;
    struct node_struct *next;
};

typedef struct node_struct Node;

struct queue_struct {
    Node *head, *tail;
};

typedef struct queue_struct Queue;
```

```
void push(Queue **q, char *word) 
{
    // q hasn't been allocated
    if (*q == NULL) {
        (*q) = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    }

    Node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word));
    strcpy(temp->data, word);
    temp->next = NULL;

    if ((*q)->head == NULL) {
        (*q)->head = (*q)->tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        (*q)->tail->next = temp;
        (*q)->tail = temp;
    }
}
```

I will use `push` to pushes a string word to the back of a queue q. Instead
of keeping the pointer to the array, it keeps a copy of the word inside the queue.

Finally, I want to deallocates the queue as well as all items in it. So, I use `free()` and this is what I write.

```
void delete(Queue *q) 
{
    Node *temp;
    for (temp = q->head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        free(temp->data);    
        free(temp);
    }
    free(q);
}
```

But, this lead to segmentation fault.
Why this happen, and how can I fix this?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word))` should be `malloc(strlen(word) + 1)`. You don't need `sizeof(char)` because `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. But you do need `+ 1` because the string length does not include the zero byte at the end of the string. For example, the string `"hi"` has a string length of 2, but requires 3 bytes of memory.

Comment: You have two malloc per node so you need 2 frees per loop iteration.

Comment: @AllanWind Could you explain for me how and why, I just started to learn c, it's hard to understand.

Comment: Sure... count number of mallocs in your push.  You have 1 for the queue, then 1 for data and one for the node.  This means you need free data, free node in the loop, and free the q (like you do).  I am working on an answer for you.

Comment: @AllanWind Now I `free(temp)` in the loop but it sill has segmentation fault TT, I already edited my post you can check how I write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you `malloc()` a string you need to allocate an extra byte for the terminating '\0'.
2. In `delete()` you need to have two frees in the loop followed by a free of the queue (reverse order of what would happen in the push; except in this case it's easier to deallocate from head).  You need temporary variable `t2` here to remember the next element so you can update your loop variable `t`.
3. You need to initialize head when creating the initial queue.
4. (Not fixed) Check that `malloc()` and `strdup()` succeed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node_struct {
    char *data;
    struct node_struct *next;
} Node;

typedef struct queue_struct {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} Queue;

void push(Queue **q, const char *word) {
    if (!*q) {
        *q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
        (*q)->head = NULL;
    }

    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(temp->data, word);
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (!(*q)->head) {
        (*q)->head = temp;
        (*q)->tail = temp;
    } else {
        (*q)->tail->next = temp;
    }
}

void delete(Queue *q) {
    for(Node *t = q->head; t;) {
        free(t->data);
        Node *t2 = t->next;
        free(t);
        t = t2;
    }
    free(q);
}

int main(void) {
    Queue *q = NULL;
    push(&q, "test");
    push(&q, "test2");
    delete(q);
}
```

and here is the valgrind output:

```
==762222== HEAP SUMMARY:
==762222==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==762222==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 59 bytes allocated
==762222== 
==762222== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==762222== 
==762222== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==762222== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

To simplify `push()` a bit you can use a double pointer to `Node` (`p`), `calloc()` to initialize head and `strdup()` to allocate and copy the string:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L // for strdup()
#include <string.h>

void push(Queue **q, const char *word) {
    Node **p;
    if (!*q) {
        (*q) = calloc(1, sizeof(Queue));
        p = &(*q)->tail;
    } else
        p = &(*q)->tail->next;

    (*p) = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*p)->data = strdup(word);
    (*p)->next = NULL;
    
    if (!(*q)->head)
        (*q)->head = *p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is that you are accessing freed data:

```
for (temp = q->head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
    free(temp->data);    
    free(temp);
}
```

When `temp = temp->next` is evaluated, `temp` is freed.  You have to capture the pointer before you free the structure.  One way to do it would be this (but there are other ways that are equivalent).

```
temp = q->head;
while (temp != NULL)
{
    free(temp->data);    
    Node *next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    temp = next;
}
```

You also are writing out of bounds with:

```
temp->data = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word));
strcpy(temp->data, word);
```

Use `strdup()`, or use `malloc(strlen(word) + 1);` to allocate enough space for the null byte that `strcpy()` places after the data.  Since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, there's no need to multiply by `sizeof(char)`.